# How to not return immediately to shell when VSCode is executed from shell

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, prompt

When I open a file in VSCode form Bash by typing `code ${FilePath}` it returns immediately i.e. I can start typing next command before closing the file.

If I do the samething with other editors like `gedit ${FileFpath}` the prompt waits for me to close the file.

I need this behavior with Vscode, as I am executing a bashscript which open a file in the middle, and the next process should occur only after the file is closed.

How can I make the bash prompt wait for me to close the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked:

```
code --wait ${FilePath}
```